# Bootstrap nav-bar not collapsing after being expanded (hamburger icon)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've run into a small issue whilst using Bootstrap. Every time I expand my menu (burger icon) it doesn't collapse after I attempt to close it. Could you please let me know where I've gone wrong & what I could do to avoid this issue in the future, thank you.

```
    <body>
              <nav id="mainNavBar" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CANDY</a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navLinks"
                  aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

        
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navLinks">
        
                  <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">HOME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                      <a class="nav-link" href="#">TICKETS</a>
                    </li>
        
                  </ul>
    
                </div>
              </nav>`
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*emphasized text*

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <!-- Required meta tags -->
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <title>Hello, world!</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <nav id="mainNavBar" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
         <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CANDY</a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navLinks"
            aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
         <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navLinks">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">HOME</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">ABOUT</a>
               </li>
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">TICKETS</a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </nav>
      `
      <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->
      <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
      <!--
         <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
         -->
   </body>
</html>
```

I try it and works perfectly. Make sure you are using correct bootstrap version.